# How to determine the length of composition series of the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> How to determine the length of composition series of the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$?

Help me.

Comment: Hint: when is a finite $\mathbb{Z}$-module simple?

Comment: Can you explain more precisely to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** If $n=p^k$, $k\ge 1$, then $0=p^k\Bbb Z/p^k\Bbb Z<p^{k-1}\Bbb Z/p^k\Bbb Z<\cdots<\Bbb Z/p^k\Bbb Z$ is a series of composition of length $k$.

Can you generalize this to the case $n=p_1^{k_1}\cdots p_r^{k_r}$, $k_i\ge 1$ and $r\ge 2$?

**Edit.** Let's try the next step: $n=p^kq^l$. Then $$0<p^{k-1}q^l\Bbb Z/p^kq^l\Bbb Z<\cdots<pq^l\Bbb Z/p^kq^l\Bbb Z<q^l\Bbb Z/p^kq^l\Bbb Z<q^{l-1}\Bbb Z/p^kq^l\Bbb Z<\cdots<\Bbb Z/p^kq^l\Bbb Z$$ is a series of composition of length ...

Comment: I'll try to generalize this

Comment: It's complicated!:( Can you explain more precise?

Comment: Length $k+l$. Is it right?

Comment: I need to see the form of composition series of the $Z$-module $Z_{n}$. Can you show it?

Comment: @chuyenvien94 Do exactly what I did for two primes in the general case when $n$ has $r$ primes in its decomposition. Will find a composition series of length $k_1+\cdots+k_r$.